# Trying to add two integers but vector error

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have been trying to read two numbers as string, convert them into int vectors, then add them for my lab at school. I have tried adding 1 + 1 to find this error:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program: C:\windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140D.dll File: c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xstring Line: 1681
>
> Expression: vector subscript out of range
>
> For more information on how your program can cause an assertion
>   failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
>
> (Press Retry to debug the application)

I have tried retrying but it opens up another dialog box that says the debug reached a breakpoint, at which point I could not continue debugging. Here is my code for those of you interested (Microsoft Visual Studio Compiler):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void input(string &largeString1, string &largeString2);
void convert(string largeString1, string largeString2, vector<int> &largeInt1, vector<int> &largeInt2);
int asciiToInt(char ch);
void add(vector<int> largeInt1, vector<int> largeInt2, vector<int> &finalInt);
void output(const vector<int> finalInt);

int main()
{
    string largeString1;
    string largeString2;
    vector<int> largeInt1(12, 0);
    vector<int> largeInt2(12, 0);
    vector<int> finalInt(13, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        input(largeString1, largeString2);
        convert(largeString1, largeString2, largeInt1, largeInt2);
        add(largeInt1, largeInt2, finalInt);
        output(finalInt);
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
void input(string &largeString1, string &largeString2)
{
    cout << "Input:" << endl << endl;
    cin >> largeString1;
    cin >> largeString2;
}
void convert(string largeString1, string largeString2, vector<int> &largeInt1, vector<int> &largeInt2)
{
    int size1 = size(largeString1);
    int size2 = size(largeString2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        int dynamicsize1 = size1 - i;
        largeInt1[11 - i] = asciiToInt(largeString1[dynamicsize1 ]);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
    {
        int dynamicsize2 = size2 - j;
        largeInt2[11 - j] = asciiToInt(largeString2[dynamicsize2 ]);
    }
}
int asciiToInt(char ch)
{
    return (ch - '0');
}
void add(vector<int> largeInt1, vector<int> largeInt2, vector<int> &finalInt)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        if (largeInt1[11 - i] + largeInt2[11 - i] >= 10)
        {
            finalInt[12 - i] = finalInt[12 - i] + largeInt1[11 - i] + largeInt2[11 - i] - 10;
            finalInt[12 - i - 1] = 1;
        }
        else
            finalInt[12 - i] = finalInt[12 - i] + largeInt1[11 - i] + largeInt2[11 - i];
    }
}
void output(const vector<int> finalInt)
{
    cout << endl << "Output:" << endl << endl << "The sum is: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
        cout << finalInt[i];
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm not too sure, but I think my problem may lie in my add or convert functions but I don't know what exactly has gone wrong :(

Comment: Rather than having `convert` convert both strings, have it convert just one string, and call it twice (with different arguments).

Comment: Which line of your code causes the assertion (look at the call stack)?  Which element of the string is it trying to access, how many elements does the string have?

Answer (score 1):

Use this to convert your string:

```
void convert(string largeString1, string largeString2, vector<int> &largeInt1, vector<int> &largeInt2)
{
    int size1 = largeString1.size();
    int size2 = largeString2.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
    {
        largeInt1[11 - i] = asciiToInt(largeString1[size1-1-i]);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++)
    {
        largeInt2[11 - j] = asciiToInt(largeString2[size2-1-j]);
    }
}
```